# In some Host 755 is writable folder and in some its not ? What are the changes once should make to make 755 writable

Tags: apache, security, shared-hosting, vps, chmod

In some Host 755 is writable folder and in some its not ? What are the changes once should make to make 755 writable.

Is that User Issue to whom the file is served ?

For an Instance, If file is served to user: matt and to make the file writable by apache, does it needs to be owned by apache ? or some thing similar ?

I have my own small vps and i see i have to chmod 777, but in my shared hosting cpanel, i don't have to do that, in 755 the folders are writable.

If i want to make 755 as writable folder , how can i do that with my vps ? i am running kloxo cpanel script.

Please advice How can i achieve this option in my VPS too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

755 permissions (rwx r-x r-x) will make the folder writable only for its owner, whilst allowing read and execution rights to other users.

```
rwx r-x r-x 

Owner: rwx = (4+2+1) = 7
Group: r-x = (4+1) = 5
Other: r-x = (4+1) = 5
```

If your folder has 755 permissions and needs to be writable by the Apache user you should change its owner to be the Apache user. If you have ssh access to your VPS you can do it like this:

```
chmod 755 my-folder/

chown apache my-folder/
```

Also `chmod +a` or `setfacl` (if ACL are supported in your system) can be used if you want a more complex permissions setup, like allowing both Apache user and *matt* user to write even if they are on different user groups.